# what does the number mean in current thread name?

Tags: java, multithreading, forkjoinpool

I have a question about Thread while developing Java applications.

The code below is the result of a printout of the code into the thread.currentThread();

```
Thread[ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2,5,main]
```

Does 1 mean the index of the pool?

Does 2 mean worker number?

I don't know exactly the number meaning of 1, 2, 5.

Thanks.

Comment: 5 mean thread priority,1 is index of pool and 2 is index of worker in current pool.you can get detail form Thread toString() method

Comment: Some kinds of `Thread` may not have those numbers. If you want the facts about a particular `Thread` object interrogate its methods: [`getId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getId()), [`getPriority`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getPriority()), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you look in ForkJoinPull class you can find one of many constructors

```
ForkJoinPool(...){
  ....
  this.workerNamePrefix = "ForkJoinPool-" + nextPoolId() + "-worker-";
  ....
}
```

where`nextPoolId()` it's poolNumberSequence. After initialization workerNamePrefix will  has next value - "ForkJoinPool-1-worker-...".
after that in method `final WorkQueue registerWorker(ForkJoinWorkerThread wt) {}` will set thread name in string 1414 (wt.setName(prefix.concat(Integer.toString(tid)))) where wt is ForkJoinWorkerThread and tid are thread's pids.
This name you showed in your output.